# Duplicate Entry '0' for key PRIMARY when uploading to Wordpress Media Folder

Tags: wordpress, file-upload, duplicates, media

It's unclear at what point this began, but a client of mine noticed errors occurring when uploading images to Wordpress.

1. When uploading from the Media library, if using the bulk file uploader, the image remains on crunching indefinitely.
2. When uploading from the Media library, if using the single file uploader, the file appears to upload, but then does not appear in the media library.
3. When uploading from the "Featured Image" link or when uploading from within a page or post, the browser coughs up an error that simply reads:

   ```
   name_of_image.jpg
   ```

   An error occurred in the upload. Please try again later.

The following is the most recent entry in the debug log:

```
[10-Oct-2017 05:39:05 UTC] WordPress database error Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY' for query INSERT INTO `wp_posts` (`post_author`, `post_date`, `post_date_gmt`, `post_content`, `post_content_filtered`, `post_title`, `post_excerpt`, `post_status`, `post_type`, `comment_status`, `ping_status`, `post_password`, `post_name`, `to_ping`, `pinged`, `post_modified`, `post_modified_gmt`, `post_parent`, `menu_order`, `post_mime_type`, `guid`) VALUES (1, '2017-10-09 23:39:05', '2017-10-10 05:39:05', '', '', 'taco2', '', 'inherit', 'attachment', 'open', 'closed', '', 'taco2', '', '', '2017-10-09 23:39:05', '2017-10-10 05:39:05', 0, 0, 'image/jpeg', 'http://www.[thesite].com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/taco2.jpg') made by media_handle_upload, wp_insert_attachment, wp_insert_post
```

Actions I've taken:

I've completely deleted their hosting account after backing up the data and folder structure, recreated a fresh installation with no added plugins and no added themes, made sure the database was up to date.  The folder structure has been recursively given the correct permissions as well.

I can't figure it out...I've decided that it MUST be something in the data, but I'm not 100% on that.  Maybe 85%.

Any ideas?

Comment: Has something changed the table definition and dropped auto_increment from the primary key maybe?

Comment: There might be a custom media upload query adding the same key, check the theme.